How can I install Jython in Sketchware?
I'm trying to use Jython in a Sketchware project to run some Python code. I'm not sure how to install and set up Jython in Sketchware. Could someone guide me through the steps required to integrate Jython into my Sketchware project? Any help would be appreciated!
I'm trying to use Jython in a Sketchware project to run some Python code. I downloaded the Jython standalone JAR file and tried to include it in my Sketchware project by copying it into the "libs" folder. I expected this to allow me to import and use Jython in my Sketchware project. However, I don't see any way to actually run the Python code, and the app crashes when I try to launch it. Could someone guide me through the steps required to integrate Jython into my Sketchware project? Any help would be appreciated!
